How to Fix Wooden Stairs Damaged By TSP
So, my family is trying to move out of out current house, and we were cleaning it in order to get it ready for showings. I was cleaning the stairs when, whoops! I turned into a complete idiot and used a TSP spray that wasn't supposed to be used on wood and damaged it. Now I need to find a way to cover it up or do something. Is there anything that can be done. Please, I am desperate for help here.
This is what the stairs look like: https://i.postimg.cc/ZqmJ34RL/20240803-144017.jpg

If real wood, then sanding away the stain and refinishing is usually the best.  Those stairs look too good for coverings, but if the stain is deep, might be an option.
